# SSIS Adding column to excel sheet template destination when importing from SQL Table Source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, excel

I have an excel sheet template that has 3 columns. I also have a SQL server table that has the same 3 columns plus an additional 4th column. I need to import all 4 columns from the SQL table into the excel spreed sheet template. My problem is that when I try to MAP the columns in SSIS I can only map the 3 columns that the Table and excel sheet have in common. How can I have SSIS import all 4 columns and not just the 3 columns that the source and destination have in common? Is there a way I can have SSIS add the additional field column to my excel spread sheet destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do Export data from the database (using the wizard - Import\Export)

select -- write a query to specify data transfer.

[image]

If you are creating package from scratch using BIDS, then in the execute sql task editor, in the sql statement

[image]

then in the data flow task in the source query specify T-SQL query as below :

[image]